# Paginate for a simple loop

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've got this code which simply displays all the posts for a particular author:

```
<?php
    $all_active_tasks = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'       => -1,
    'offset'            => 0,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'author'            => '1',
    'post_type'         => 'post'
    )
);
foreach($all_active_tasks as $post) :
$category = get_the_category();
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div class="the-post">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></p>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But what I can't figure out is how to paginate the results to say 10 per page. I've looked at the official codex but nothing I tried seemed to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paged` together with `posts_per_page` parameters. [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). You can grab current page like this:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ?: ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ?: 1 );
```

and then use it in your query:

```
$all_active_tasks = get_posts(array(
   'posts_per_page'    => 10,
   'post_status'       => 'publish',
   'author'            => '1',
   'post_type'         => 'post',
   'paged'             => $paged
));
```

In this way if you put `/page/2/` at the end of your url, the query will return the posts from 11 to 20.

How to create the pagination itself, you can check these articles:
[here](http://sgwordpress.com/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/) and [here](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin).

Comment: This led me to eventually getting it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `'numberposts' => -1` means to get all records. You have to set for the first 10 records (0-9 records)

```
'numberposts'       => 10,
'offset'            => 0,
```

And for next 10, (10-19 records)

```
'numberposts'       => 10,
'offset'            => 10,
```

And for next 10, (20-29 records)

```
'numberposts'       => 10,
'offset'            => 20,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this working code

put this function in functions.php file of your active theme

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {



  if (empty($pagerange)) {

    $pagerange = 2;

  }





  global $paged;

  if (empty($paged)) {

    $paged = 1;

  }

  if ($numpages == '') {

    global $wp_query;

    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if(!$numpages) {

        $numpages = 1;

    }

  }



  $pagination_args = array(

    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',

    'format'          => 'page/%#%',

    'total'           => $numpages,

    'current'         => $paged,

    'show_all'        => False,

    'end_size'        => 1,

    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,

    'prev_next'       => True,

    'prev_text'       => __('<i class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></i>'),

    'next_text'       => __('<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>'),

    'type'            => 'plain',

    'add_args'        => false,

    'add_fragment'    => ''

  );



  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);



  if ($paginate_links) {

    echo "<div class='col-md-12'><nav class='custom-pagination pagination'>";

      echo $paginate_links;

    echo "</nav></div>";

  }



}
```

and here is your modified code to work for pagination

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $all_active_tasks   = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'offset'            => 0,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'author'            => '1',
    'post_type'         => 'post'
    )
);
foreach($all_active_tasks as $post) :
$category = get_the_category();
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div class="the-post">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></p>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
        custom_pagination(count($all_active_tasks),"",$paged);
    }?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```